# MySQL - match columns between two tables / outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to do something perhaps not too common and I'm getting a bit confused about the best method.

I have two separate tables in a DB:

```
Tbl1:              Tbl2:

X                  Y    Z
---                ---  ---
```

In a nutshell I need to match equal rows between columns X and Y and output the record (on the same row ID) from column Z.

```
X                  Y    Z
---                ---  ---
aaa                ccc  kkk
bbb                aaa  mmm
ccc                bbb  sss
```

Match `aaa` from `X` and `Y`, return `mmm`

Match `ccc` from `X` and `Y`, return `kkk`

Match `bbb` from `X` and `Y`, return `sss`

I think the way to go is somehow related to the JOIN query (outer?) but I cannot seem to work this out.

Could you guys put me towards the right direction?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really basic join:

```
SELECT b.z
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.x=b.y
```